# How do I write a string to a serial port using VB for UWP?

Tags: vb.net, uwp-xaml

the question is pretty self-explanatory. I’m coding a UWP app in VB to run on a raspberry pi running Windows 10 IOT core. I want to get a list of available serial ports, and parse that to a combobox, and then open the selected serial port and write strings to it. I knew how to do this before using system.IO.ports on VB.Net, but can someone explain how it’s done when writing for UWP, as the system.IO.ports is not included here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, you need to use [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication) APIs to communicate with a serial device and use [DataWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter) to write string.

You could check the official [Custom serial device sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess) to learn how to use it. There's no vb code sample in this sample, but you could check the c# code sample there. They're very similar.